# Compiler intermediate code generation three address code fjump

Tags: compiler-construction, intermediate-code

What does *FJUMP* mean in [this context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXaOK.jpg)?

> The following is a Three Address Code (TAC) Intermediate Representation for a register machine: it contains a function called `foo`, which takes an integer parameter `n` and a parameter `a` which is an array of integers. Write down the high-level language counterpart in Java-like pseudocode.
>
> ```
> label Foo:
>     res = 1
>     i = 1
> label BAR:
>     t1 = i LEQ n
>     a[1] = res
>     i = i ADD 1
>     res = res MUL i
>     JUMP BAR
> label BAZ:
> ```

I thought a jump instruction in three address code is something like "if x goto L"?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant excerpt is:

```
t1 = i LEQ n
FJUMP t1 BAZ
```

Which I take to mean "if `i` is less than or equal to `n`, jump to `BAZ`". So `FJUMP` indeed does seem to denote a conditional jump (as you read it, feel free to insert the "if" and "goto" parts yourself!).

You have to understand that three-address code is **not a language**. It is a *class* of intermediate representations (languages) that have similar characteristics, not unlike the *classes* of object-oriented or functional languages. As a compiler developer, *you* get to design your three-address code, should you opt to use such an intermediate representation.

---

On a side note, I have a feeling that students of compiler theory tend to read their textbooks too literally. If you look at a bunch of reasonably modern compilers, you are likely to find recurring patterns, but they tend to differ  quite significantly in the details.